# Allow / white list confirmation from internal target

Tags: ip

Would it be sensible to use a ping from an internal site to an allow listed IP and detect the return to test that the allow list is working?  That would assume there is a ping service at the other end to respond.

Answer (score 1):

This just sounds like normal monitoring to me, so yeah it makes sense.  You can use things like prometheus (free/open source) to do this (with an exporter).

- https://github.com/czerwonk/ping_exporter

Prometheus can keep a time series history and alert on the results (if they degrade).  Alerts can be sent to things like slack or pager-duty (so you can get a phone call or message immediately if it stops working).

Lots of paid services exist for this too obviously.